# Handle multiple clients two-way communication using sockets in c

Tags: c, sockets, select

this is my first time building a server that accepts multiple clients in c, and I need to use select to achieve this.

I am currently able to send info to the server, but when the server does a send back, the info ends up triggering the select statement on the server side, rather than actually going through to the client. Help please :(

Client:

```
sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);
if(sockfd < 0) syserr("can't open socket");
printf("create socket...\n");

memset(&serv_addr, 0, sizeof(serv_addr));
serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
serv_addr.sin_addr = *((struct in_addr*)server->h_addr);
serv_addr.sin_port = htons(portno);

if(connect(sockfd, (struct sockaddr*)&serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr)) < 0)
    syserr("can't connect to server");
printf("connect...\n");

// send the server our username
n = (int) send(sockfd, argv[3], strlen(argv[3]), 0) ;
if(n < 0) syserr("Can't send username to server\n");
printf("Username sent to server\n");

// wait for response, n ALWAYS RETURNS 0
n = (int) recv(sockfd, buffer, strlen(buffer), 0);

printf("buffer:\n%s\n",buffer) ;
if(n < 0) syserr("Can't receive from server\n");
else if (n == 0)
{
    close(sockfd) ;
    syserr("Server disconnected you due to duplicate username.\n") ;
}
else buffer[n] = '\0';



while ( done == 0 )
{
// rest of program loop, not being reached yet
}

close(sockfd);
return 0;
```

Server:

```
portno = atoi(argv[1]);

sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
if(sockfd < 0) syserr("can't open socket");
printf("create socket...\n");

memset(&serv_addr, 0, sizeof(serv_addr));
serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
serv_addr.sin_port = htons(portno);

if(bind(sockfd, (struct sockaddr*)&serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr)) < 0)
    syserr("can't bind");
printf("bind socket to port %d...\n", portno);

listen(sockfd, 5);

FD_ZERO(&fds) ;
FD_SET(sockfd, &fds) ;

for(;;)
{
    printf("wait on port %d...\n", portno);
    addrlen = sizeof(clt_addr);
    //newsockfd = accept(sockfd, (struct sockaddr*)&clt_addr, &addrlen);
    //if(newsockfd < 0) syserr("can't accept");

    readfds = fds ;
    int result = select(FD_SETSIZE, &readfds, NULL, NULL, NULL) ;

    // no timeout val, so never 0 return
    if(result == -1)
        syserr("Error on select call.\n") ;

    int i ;
    for( i = 0; i < FD_SETSIZE; i++ ) // loop through set of fds
    {
        if (FD_ISSET(i, &readfds)) // if fd i has data available to be read
        {
            if (i == sockfd) // if we are reading from server fd
            {
                if (numClients < maxClients) // if we could fit more clients
                {
                    // place incoming client's fd into array of all clients
                    clients[numClients].clientfd = accept(sockfd, (struct sockaddr*)&clt_addr, &addrlen);
                    if(clients[numClients].clientfd < 0) syserr("Error on accept.\n");

                    FD_SET(clients[numClients].clientfd, &fds) ;

                    // receive the username sent by user
                    printf("new incoming connection, block on receive\n");
                    n = (int) recv(clients[numClients].clientfd, clients[numClients].username, 30, 0);
                    if(n < 0) syserr("can't receive from client");

                    clients[numClients].username[n] = '\0';

                    printf("New user accepted: %s\n", clients[numClients].username) ;
                    clients[numClients].online = 1 ;

                    // NOW I NEED TO SEND SOME INFO BACK                        
        /// THIS IS THE PART THAT IS NOT SENDING BACK PROPERLY
        /// IT IS ACTUALLY TRIGERRING THE SELECT ON THE SECOND ITERATION
                    n = (int) send(clients[numClients].clientfd, "Hey\nThis\nis\na\ntest", 18, 0) ;
                    if(n < 0) syserr("Can't send userlist to client.\n");
                    printf("n: %d\n", n) ; // My print returns the expected 18
                    printf("User List sent to client.\n") ; // This also prints

                    ++numClients ; // extend client counter
                }
                else
                {
                    printf("Sorry, we are full.\n") ;
                }
            }
            else // not server file descriptor
            {
        /// On my second iteration This is triggered through the ‘select’ because of my send back above

                // check if recv returns 0 for disconnect
                n = (int) recv(clients[i].clientfd, buffer, sizeof(buffer), 0);
                if(n < 0) syserr("can't receive from client"); // I actually get an error for bad fd

                if( n == 0 ) // disconnected
                {
        // This code not reached yet
                }
                else // A message is being sent
                {
                    // This code not reached yet
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
close(sockfd); 
return 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

On the server side, your main problem is, that in the `else` that is triggered on your 2nd iteration through select, it is `i` that you should `recv()` from, not `clients[i].clientfd`. They are unlikely to be the same number, though I can not be sure, since you did not post all the code. (Please *always* http://www.sscce.org/ )

There are other problems also. I will mentiont the ones I immediately noticed

The first parameter to select should be something like `maxfd + 1` where `int maxfd = MYMAX(maxfd, new_fd_from_accept/listen)`
and `#define MYMAX(a,b) (((a)>(b))?(a):(b))`. Initialize `maxfd` to `sockfd` to start with. It is kind of wasteful to loop all the way to FD_SETSIZE.

I can not see if you initialize variable properly, so make sure you do. If you are on Linux, please read `man select`and `man select_tut`.

Using `recv()`on a socket you just accepted, without it being indicated to do so from `select()`, seems to work since you do a blocking read, but I would still suggest putting the accepted fd in a fd_set and read from it when `select()` indicates it is ok to do so.

*EDIT*: See Serge Ballestas answer for client side issues.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot see how you declare `buffer` in client, but I can see you use it that way :

```
n = (int) recv(sockfd, buffer, strlen(buffer), 0);
```

If you have a 0 as first character in `buffer`, `strlen(buffer)` is `0`, and `n` will always be 0.

If you have `char buffer[...];`, just use :

```
n = (int) recv(sockfd, buffer, sizeof(buffer), 0);
```

If you use dynamic allocation on the stack : `buffer = (char *) malloc(size);`, do :

```
n = (int) recv(sockfd, buffer, size, 0);
```

Comment: Good catch, I was too busy looking at the server side.